# What is the advantage of binding multiple event listeners to same event in Node.js

Tags: node.js

Consider the following example. When Binding a event listener to a event type can just fulfill the output, what is the significance of binding multiple event listeners to same even?

```
readStream.on("data", function(data) {console.log('I have some data here.');          
}); 
readStream.on("data", function(data) {console.log('I have some data here too.');
});
```

Comment: It can be useful when there are different actions that each listener is taking. For example, with an `http.Server` – `server.on('request', logRequestToFile); server.on('request', respondToRequest);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly it's for modularity.  You wouldn't likely do that in the same file, unless you're defining your listener functions somewhere else and then composing them in one place.